# Unable to set local variables in helper method when called from a particular view

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

It appears that when I call a helper method from one of my views, I am unable to set any new local variables. Name doesn't matter - everything I set is nil.

From most views, everything is fine:

```
editable = true
html << 'Editable: ' + editable.to_s
```

Outputs `Editable: true`

However, from one of my partials, the output is `Editable:` indicating nil.

I'm attempting to isolate what is different about this particular view file - posting swaths of files won't help anyone.

With this information (I know it's not a lot), can anyone tell me why I might not be able to set local variables in a helper method?

Comment: Is it possible there is a conflict with the name of the partial? Rails creates a local variable named after the model: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables But even then, you should be able to override it.

Comment: A conflict as in there's more than 1 by the same name? I specify the folder from the render :partial and there's no other files by that name. I think it may be related to this issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128406/ruby-on-rails-initializing-instance-variables-with-helpers-in-view. I'm debugging ivars from the different views and if that doesn't turn something up, I'll move the helper code to a partial which is where it should be anyways.

Comment: Sorry never mind, misread the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a 'stupid mistake' on my part but I can't entirely blame myself. Rails behaved *very* oddly.

`editable = true` came just after this line in my code:

```
target_str == '#overview' ? target_str = '#section' : #nothing
```

It's weird, I know. I was getting errors without the `:`. I've changed the line to this

```
target_str = '#section' if target_str == '#overview'
```

It should do the same thing IMO, but of course doesn't. Despite being a 1 line if, it was including the next statement which was `editable = true`. This explains why it was only happening for 1 of my views as well - the only one where the statement evaluated as true.